# Connecting to a local MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to my local MySQL server with MySQL Workbench. When I do so, I get a "Can't connect to MySQL server..." error. I can connect just fine if I SSH into the machine and start up MySQL there, so I know it's not an issue there.

Is there something special I need to do to tell my MySQL server that "outsiders" can connect to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
```

To solve my problem, I did two things:

1. I created a new user: 'admin'@'%'
2. I commented out the "bind-address" line in my.cnf.

Now it works.

Comment: Note: you must restart MySQL after this in order for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

- mysqld is not running with --skip-networking
- or --bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Also make sure you have allowed your client end access to port 3306(by default) on the server and it is not firewalled.

There is more information and all you need to know on [this page in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html).

Comment: Thanks, Richard. My solution turned out to be something a little different but your answer put me on the right track.

Comment: Jason: Glad you got sorted. I forgot to mention the user@%. D'oh. Never mind you got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

yes you do - MySQL authentication is done on a username and host basis.

The best bet is to create an admin user that can auth from any host (% wildcard).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: I did that. Apparently something more needs to be done because that didn't take care of it. (I made sure I could log in with my new user locally before trying it remotely.)